# De Bruijn Graph Code Python 3

Tags: python

This is for a class assignment. I'm new to coding and was advised to use Python since it is easier to deal with. The point of the assignment is to take a list of kmers and assemble the superstring, in this case DNA nucleotides and assemble the DNA sequence. We need to use the Euler path (algorithm), which I still haven't figured out to do. Right now I'm working on, one trying to load my kmer list to Python (haven't figured that out yet) and building the de Bruijn graph. NOTE: I'm not loading the list of kmers since I haven't figured out how to do that yet. This is just a random string of DNA that I'm typing in.

Here is my code:

```
def de_bruijn_ize(st, k):
edges = []
nodes = set()
for i in range(len(st) - k + 1):
    edges.append((st[i:+k-1], st[i+1:i+k]))
    nodes.add(st[i:i+k-1])
    nodes.add(st[i+1:i+k])
return nodes, edges

nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize(“CCGGTTAAACGTC”, 3)
print(nodes)
print(edges)
```

I'm receiving the following message when I try to run it:

File "practiceassembly.txt", line 11
    nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize(“CCGGTTAAACGTC”, 3)
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. And if anybody can provide good resources for this type of problem, I would really appreciate it also.

I made a little progress. I have managed to open my kmer file with the following:
Yeah, I've managed to get that going:

```
f = open("kmers.txt")
print(f.read())
st = f.read()
def de_bruijn_ize(st, k):
edges = []
nodes = set()
for i in range(len(st) - k + 1):
    edges.append((st[i:+k-1], st[i+1:i+k]))
    nodes.add(st[i:i+k-1])
    nodes.add(st[i+1:i+k])
return nodes, edges

nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize(st, 4)
print(nodes)
print(edges)
```

And I get my list of kmers:

AAAC
AACA
AACG
AAGG
ACAC
ACAG
ACGC
ACGG
ACTG
AGCA
AGGA
AGGC
ATCA
ATTC
CAAG
CACA
CACG
CAGG
CATC
CGCG
CGGT
CGTA
CGTG
CTAA
CTCT
CTGG
CTTA
GACT
GCAT
GCGT
GCTC
GCTT
GGAC
GGCA
GGCT
GGGT
GGTG
GGTT
GTAT
GTGC
GTGG
GTTT
TAAA
TAAC
TATT
TCAA
TCAC
TCGT
TCTA
TGCT
TGGC
TGGG
TTAA
TTCA
TTCG
TTTC
TTTT
set()
[]
But the rest is not implemented. I think I'm almost there in getting this to work (maybe I'm just being hopeful here) but I just need a little help.

Comment: “ and ” don't look like normal quotes

Comment: There shouldn't be any special formatting since I'm using a simple text editor to write the code. And I'm using the regular "and"  quotes. I think it's actually the formatting above that makes them look a bit funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from any errors in logic the quotes in your line:

```
    nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize(“CCGGTTAAACGTC”, 3)
```

Are some other weird character, replace it with:

```
    nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize("CCGGTTAAACGTC", 3)
```

That is valid in python 3.  I'm curious what those quotes are.

Comment: First, thanks for the help. However, like I stated above, Im using text editor on my Mac. I've been trying different codes. Just yesterday, I was actually able to print out my list of kmers from a text file and it worked just fine. The code has not been copied and pasted from anywhere, I typed it up myself. I've been doing a lot of reading and, as far as I can tell, I can use text editor, correct?

Comment: Ahh ok...I guess I had to save it as a .py doc for it to read the "and" quotes.....Can anybody add hints as to how I can read in my list of kmers into the script? I'm driving myself nuts trying to figure it out....or any good suggestions?

Comment: what form are your kmers in, a csv file or some other form?

Comment: They are in a txt file. They are in the same folder as my python script. I've been able to print it on my terminal (I did that for practice) but I need to take those kmers and build the deBuijn graph, as a first step to complete my assignment. I've been doing a whole bunch of reading and experimenting but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: [file reading in python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python)
I'm not sure what form your data is in but there is a guide here to open files so you'd want something like file = open("kmers.txt", "r")

Comment: and I get my list of kmers.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes used are not standard (maybe a copy paste from a pdf?):

replace:

```
nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize(“CCGGTTAAACGTC”, 3)
```

with:

```
nodes, edges = de_bruijn_ize("CCGGTTAAACGTC", 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def read(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.readline().rstrip()
        k = int(f.readline().rstrip())
    return text,k
def edges(str,num):
    i = 0
    edge_list = []
    while i +num <= len(str):
        sub = str[i:i+num]
        edge_list.append(sub)
        i+=1
    print(*edge_list)
def nodes(str,num):
    i = 0
    edge_list = []
    while i+num-1 <= len(str):
        sub = str[i:i+(num-1)]
        edge_list.append(sub)
        i+=1
    print(*edge_list)
text,k = read("L4.txt")
edges(text,k)
nodes(text,k)
```